# Chrome: Is it possible to create button combination to run custom javascript on page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to create a simple button combination, that when it's clicked it will run these javascript lines on the page:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("yt-uix-button-content")[18].click();
document.getElementsByClassName("addto-playlist-item")[1].click();
```

Is it possible, or is there extension that could help me do this?Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I happened upon this question when looking into a similar issue. What I ended up doing is a bookmark-link with the custom-js as URL (has to start with `javascript:`) and then I just click it. Works like a charm. For your question, just add a new bookmark to your bookmark-panel and set the following as URL:

```
javascript:function hola(){ document.getElementsByClassName("yt-uix-button-content")[18].click(); document.getElementsByClassName("addto-playlist-item")[1].click(); } hola();
```